# Api para formulario desplegable web (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, api, aplicación-web

**No es una pregunta de opinion**

Hola buenas, estoy trabajando en una pagina web, mas concretamente en el apartado de **Registro de usuario**.

Como cualquier formulario, es necesario introducir *pais, provincia, ciudad y codigo postal*, y me gustaría mejorar este apartado introduciendo una lista desplegable en el formulario que permita elegir las opciones antes mencionadas  directamente de la lista, en vez de dejar que el usuario introduzca manualmente los nombres, todo esto con el fin de simplificar el formulario.

Me preguntaba si existe alguna API o algúna libreria que ya implemente la lista completa de paises y sus respectivas provincias y ciudades, ya que muchos registros de usuario implementan esta misma funcion y no creo que todos lo hagan a mano.

Me encuentro trabajando con `JavaScript`

Muchas gracias, creo haberme explicado bien y recalco que no es una pregunta de opinion, no quiero saber si hay una forma mejor que otra, solo si hay una api o una libreria que cumpla con mis necesidades, gracias.

Comment: No es pregunta de opinión, de acuerdo, pero sí sobre recomendaciones de librerías, por lo que puede que termine cerrada. Por lo general, se usan las APIs de mapa y las más comunes son [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview?hl=es-419) y [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html) para OpenStrettMap. Para lo que quieres hacer, las opciones suelen ser de pago, porque se requieren muchas peticiones.

Comment: Aunque también puedes descargar la base de datos de [MaxMind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data?lang=en) y crear tus propios scripts.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias!!